# Pages are loaded twice

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

It appears my Drupal pages load twice.

If I added debugging such as drupal_set_message() in methods such as includes/common.inc drupal_build_css_cache() and it gets called twice.

I also have modules that add to the data to the DB these also get called twice and I really only want certain DB updates to be called once.

Is this normal for drupal?

Could it be a devel or optimization thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if your page get's loaded more than once, the best place to test that would be in `hook_init` in a module, or `hook_preprocess_page` in your theme.

It's hard to say anything concrete with the info you've given, but the same function can be called several times on a single page load. If you want help with a concrete issue, you should post some relevant code.

I've never experience Drupal loading a page more than once or similar.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll properly diagnose this issue with hook_preprocess_page

Comment: when I use watchdog inside hook_preprocess_page, it is printing twice. This occurs only when we close the browser and use the url. But when we open the same url in another tab, it doesnt occurs. Could you pls share your thoughtsto debug it